# Python PIL: Draw text below an image

Tags: python-imaging-library

how do I draw text below an image using PIL? I have already drawn text on the image without problems and I am now trying to draw **below** the image without success.

My text drawing line:

draw.text((0,img.size[1]),text= mytext, font = font, fill = img.getpixel((502,10))

I am not getting any errors

Comment: So, no error - what's the problem then?

Comment: You would need to create a new, larger image, and draw the old image onto it (at the top), in order for there to be any space below the old image to put the text.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the problem is that no text is drawn and no error is shown.

Comment: @jasonharper I am still learning the PIL module I will try to work around and see if I can succeed. Thanks